# How do I use pagination with Django class based generic ListViews?

Tags: django

How do I use pagination with Django 1.3?

The documentation is not very clear on this.

- What goes to my `views.py`?
- What goes to my template?
- What goes to my URLconf file?

Comment: maybe this blog post will help: https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/django-pagination-with-class-based-view/

Answer (score 353):

I think you ask for information about using pagination with the new class based views since, with traditional function based views, it is easy to find. I found that just by setting the `paginate_by` variable is enough to activate the pagination. See in *[Class-based generic views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#multiple-object-mixins)*.

For example, in your `views.py`:

```
import models
from django.views.generic import ListView

class CarListView(ListView):
    model = models.Car      # shorthand for setting queryset = models.Car.objects.all()
    template_name = 'app/car_list.html'  # optional (the default is app_name/modelNameInLowerCase_list.html; which will look into your templates folder for that path and file)
    context_object_name = "car_list"    #default is object_list as well as model's_verbose_name_list and/or model's_verbose_name_plural_list, if defined in the model's inner Meta class
    paginate_by = 10  #and that's it !!
```

In your template (`car_list.html`), you can include a pagination section like this (we have some context variables available: `is_paginated`, `page_obj`, and `paginator`).

```
{# .... **Normal content list, maybe a table** .... #}
{% if car_list %}
    <table id="cars">
        {% for car in car_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ car.model }}</td>
                <td>{{ car.year }}</td>
                <td><a href="/car/{{ car.id }}/" class="see_detail">detail</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {# .... **Now the pagination section** .... #}
    {% if is_paginated %}
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="/cars?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="page-current">
                    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="/cars?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <h3>My Cars</h3>
    <p>No cars found!!! :(</p>
{% endif %}
{# .... **More content, footer, etc.** .... #}
```

The page to display is indicated by a GET parameter, simply adding `?page=n`, to the URL.

Comment: Thats ok, but how do you tie the template too see  the "car_list" object?

Comment: FYI you can also do this directly in urls.py:url(r'^cars/$', ListView.as_view(
        model=Car,
        paginate_by=10
    )),

Comment: lesson I learned: to find a method, open all ancestor classes in new tabs, and CTRL+F away the key word. so from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview, which we know exists from the basic tutorial, open all Ancestors links and search for "pagi"

Comment: I have been doing this, but the problem I find, is when I do extra processing on objects in the queryset, it applys them to all of the results in the database. So for a query that returns 100 objects, but shows only ten objects per page, the extra processing will be done on 100 objects.

Comment: I don't like the hardcoded urls you can replace it with: <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>

Comment: I needed to do links like `<a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>` to work on current location

Comment: @wobbily_col What was the solution to the problem you described? I have the same issue.

Comment: I didn't solve it very well. Iterated over the whole set, and ignored anything not in the current page. I am not sure if moving the code to a model manager method would allow the array slice syntax to solve the problem, but I didn't get a chance to try yet.

Comment: Note that you can also use a `page` named argument in your url pattern.

Comment: Not sure why this answer hasn't been accepted. @gath, kindly accept this answer.

Comment: with this option is there something like page_obj.last_page_number ? or how can i get the last page number?

Comment: How I make django pagination using jquery ajax?

Answer (score 50):

assume, I have a class in app/models.py named `FileExam(models.Model)`:

**app/models.py**

```
class FileExam(models.Model):
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
```

**app/views.py**

```
from app.models import FileExam
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage
from django.core.paginator import PageNotAnInteger

class FileExamListView(ListView):
    model = FileExam
    template_name = "app/exam_list.html"
    paginate_by = 10
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FileExamListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        list_exam = FileExam.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(list_exam, self.paginate_by)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            file_exams = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            file_exams = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            file_exams = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
            
        context['list_exams'] = file_exams
        return context
```

Only a little change in the `get_context_data` and added pagination code from django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view)

**app/templates/app/exam_list.html**

**normal content list**

```
<table id="exam">
  {% for exam in list_exams %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ exam.myfile }}</td>
    <td>{{ exam.date }}</td>
    <td>.....</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**paginate section**

```
{% if is_paginated %}
<ul class="pagination">
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <li>
        <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></span>
    </li>
{% endif %}
    <li class="">
        <span>Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
    </li>
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <li>
        <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></span>
    </li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <h3>Your File Exam</h3>
    <p>File not yet available</p>
{% endif %}
```

**app/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(
    r'^$', views.FileExamListView.as_view(), name='file-exam-view'),
), 
... ]
```

Comment: This doesn't look right: `context = super(SoalListView, self)...`. Did you mean: `context = super(FileExamListView, self)...`?

Comment: Yes, right! This answer has been edited by Mr. Yacin. Thank you, Mr. Yacin.

Comment: From what I tested, we can't intercept the `PageNotAnInteger` exception like you did, because if we pass a non integer via the `GET` parameter a `ValueError` exception will be raised before the `PageNotAnInteger` exception. This happens at the level of the `paginate_queryset` method of the `ListView` class. Hope this is clear

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 methods to do this.

First one is simple and just set the class field `paginate_by`. Nothing need we to do with `get_context_data` method.

The second method is a little complicated but we can gain more comprehension about pagination and customize complex pagination or several pagination. Let's see it.

It can be done in three steps.

### 1.Override `get_context_data` method of your `View`.

Pass `page_keys` and `pages` so that we can iterate the lists and avoid hard-coding .

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data()
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(self.model.objects.all().values()))
    ipc = df.groupby('ip')['ip'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
    urlc = df.groupby('url')['url'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).to_dict()

    ipc = tuple(ipc.to_dict().items())
    urlc = tuple(urlc.items())

    pages = []
    page_keys = ['page1', 'page2']
    for obj, name in zip([urlc, ipc], page_keys):
        paginator = Paginator(obj, 20)
        page = self.request.GET.get(name)
        page_ipc = obj
        try:
            page_ipc = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            page_ipc = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            page_ipc = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        pages.append(page_ipc)

    context['data'] = zip(pages, page_keys)
    return context
```

### 2.Customize your sub `template`.

We define some variables so we can iterate through the pagination list.

`pagination.html`

```
    {% if is_paginated %}
        <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li>
            <span><a href="?{{ pname }}={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        <li class="">
            <span>Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
        </li>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li>
            <span><a href="?{{ pname }}={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <h3>Your File Exam</h3>
        <p>File not yet available</p>
    {% endif %}
```

### 3.Customize outer `template`.

`index.html`

```
{% for foo,name in data %}
    <div class="col-md-3 table-responsive">

            {% for k,v in foo %}
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                    <td>{{ k }}</td>
                    <td>{{ v }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        {% include 'pagination.html' with pname=name  page_obj=foo %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```