# What happens if I don't have pagination?just keep for looping the post...why need pagination, for footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I see load more button all the time, why do I need that?also what happens if I don't have a pagination? just keep lettings the post being displayed without pagination? I don't need a footer anyway.

```
{% for post in Posts %}
<div class='col-sm-4'>
{{post.content}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

the above simple code would do it, without load more or pagination, will my webpage downgrade itself?..I really don't see the need for pagination and load more feature for my site....the reason I don't want is because I'm not sure how to write them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, with djangos generic views (ListView), pagination is literally one line to implement in a view and then the code for the template is given to you in the documentation (the bootstrap docs also have pagination example code snippets).

Your current loop is essentially the same as

```
for i in range(n):
    print i
```

As `n` increases, the more information will be printed to the screen and that leads to too much information for one person to take in. Even if they could take it all in, the majority of it they won't care about and only need the first couple results.

Therefore, without pagination, you'd have just made your user wait additional time for your server to generate the content, and for their browser to display that content (even longer with images/media).

Humans don't like waiting, don't make them when they don't need to.

Comment: ah-ha thank you, I guess I should follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907575/how-do-i-use-pagination-with-django-class-based-generic-listviews

Answer (score 0):

Every post you add will have a certain weight, especially if it also has images or other media. Your users will have to load everything you have on the load of your page. This will make your page slow to load.

Slow loading pages have poorer performance because people give up on loading.

When the loading happens bit by bit as requested by the user it won't have such impact.

Answer (score 0):

While @Haroen Viaene is correct, that is only one side of the matter. Also a big collection of posts would be very hard to navigate through if a user wants to find a certain old post he's read already for example. Also another way to go (without "load more" or pagination) is to use a search box and/or categories to separate your posts in.