# How can i determine number object show per page when using ListView pagination in django?

Tags: django, django-views, paginator

please how can i determine number of objects/page show(not number of pages) in Django when using ListView Pagination.
that's my code in `Views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

class PostList(ListView):
    model=Post
    context_object_name='all_post'
    ordering=['-created_at']
```

thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use pagination with Django class based generic ListViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907575/how-do-i-use-pagination-with-django-class-based-generic-listviews)

Comment: See [Paginating a ListView - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `paginate_by = <number of items in a page>` to your view.

For example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

class PostList(ListView):
    model=Post
    context_object_name='all_post'
    ordering=['-created_at']
    paginate_by = 10 # 10 items in a page
```