# How to paginate other model in class view?

Tags: python, django

Is there way to paginate another model in class based view in django? I have code like this. I would like to paginate comments is it possible?

```
class ShopDetailView(VisitCounter, DetailView):
    model = Item 
    template_name = 'shop/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'item'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(comment_item=self.object)
        context['form'] = CommentCreationForm()
        return context
```

Comment: Take a look into the below question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907575/how-do-i-use-pagination-with-django-class-based-generic-listviews

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, but with this approach you will need to refresh the detailview page every time to view old comments which is not code :-

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(comment_item=self.object)
    paginator = Paginator(comments, self.paginate_by)
    page = self.request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        comments = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        comments = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        comments = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        
    context['comments'] = comments
    return context
```

I Believe you should create separate view to render the comments and apply pagination on it and make ajax call to refresh the comment section whenever user click on next page.